# How to Set custom text Color in QTextEdit?

Tags: c++, css, qt, qtextedit

I have resisted asking this seemingly n00b question, but all my recent effort to achieve this task have failed. Here are the things I have tried already, all have failed! Could it be that my OpenSuse 11.3 sets system-wide style settings that apply to even my Qt app by default?

```
//I have some QTextEdit created in QDesigner -- call it myQEdit
QString str = "some content i want to display"
//trial one:
QString my_html_template = "<html><head></head><body style=\"color:__color__;\">__content__</body></html>"
myQEdit->document()->setHtml(my_html_template.replace("__color__","#99ff00").replace("__content__",str));
```

that fails, then i tried...

```
//trial two:
myQEdit->setDocument(new QTextDocument(str,this));
myQEdit->document()->setDefaultStyleSheet(" body { color:#99ff00;}");
```

I even tried setting the `!important` css flag on the `color` value i pass like:

but this failed too!

```
myQEdit->document()->setDefaultStyleSheet(" body { color:#99ff00 !important;}");
```

So I decided to set the color of my `QTextEdit` from the designer itself - by specifying my custom color in the option to set the raw html content of the `QTextEdit`. While i didnt change the content programmatically, the desired color was used. But the moment I set custom content like this:

```
myQEdit->setDocument(new QTextDocument(str));
```

I loose the color settings I'd set from `QDesigner` on the `QTextEdit`. So what is the correct way to achieve what am desiring? I know it can be done some way...

**Finally**:
After using the hint from the accepted answer below, here is how I've solved it:

```
myQEdit->setDocument(new QTextDocument(str,this));
QPalette pal;
pal.setColor(QPalette::Text, QColor::fromRgb(0,150,0));
myQEdit->setPalette(pal);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've had success changing text color of `QLabel` and `QPlainTextEdit` by changing the Palette:

```
QPalette pal;
pal.setColor(QPalette::Window, bgColor);
pal.setColor(QPalette::WindowText, fgColor);
pal.setColor(QPalette::Text, fgColor);
mylabel->setPalette(pal);
```

Comment: Worked immediately like a charm! Thanks (reflected your ans in the question)